# How to make sure the axios request is using the latest token from the redux store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, axios

I have an accessToken in my redux store. I am creating a axios client like this:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import store from '../redux/store';

const apiClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:5002/api/',
    headers: {
        Authorization:`Bearer ${store.getState().auth.accessToken}` // ???
    }
});
apiClient.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${store.getState().auth.accessToken}`; // ???

export default apiClient;
```

I want every request that is sent by the *apiClient* to contain the current value of the *accessToken* from the redux store (at the time the request is sent). And with the lines that are marked with *???*, I'm not sure whether the *Authorization* header is only set once when the *apiClient* is created, or whether the value of the header also changes when the *accessToken* in the store has been updated.
Later I want to make a request like this:

```
apiClient.get<User[]>('Users/Friends');
```

And I want the request to include the *accessToken* that is in the store at the time the request is sent not at the time the client is created. Is there a way to achieve this while the creation of the client or do I always have to put the Authorization header config with the current *accessToken* in every request?

**Now I added this code:**

```
const apiClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://192.168.178.188:5002/api/'
});

apiClient.interceptors.request.use(config => {
    config.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${store.getState().auth.accessToken}`
    return config;
});
```

Is this the most elegant solution?